# Image Banner not displaying for read-only users

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, permissions, master-page, image

On one of the Site Collections we have in SharePoint 2013, we created a custom banner. The banner is not displayed for users who have read-only access to that Site Collection. Is there away for us to fix it so that we can display this for everyone who has access to the Site Collecton? I'm looking for the following code:

```
<Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl ID=”SPSecurityTrimmedControl2″ runat=”server” PermissionsString=”AddAndCustomizePages”>
<script type=”text/javascript”>
    document.getElementById(“s4-ribbonrow”).style.display = “block”;
</script>
```

In the Master Page, but that is not there.

Comment: Did you check the permissions on the image itself?  It sounds like the Master Page is fine, but the permissions of the image might be off.

Comment: also check if the content are published, and check the place of image

Comment: The permission for the picture is the same as the parent site. all pages are published

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing what you are trying to accomplish but why wouldn't you just create a table or div in the top of the  in the table after the

```
</sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>
    <!--Hide Ribbon if Read Only Permissions -->
  <Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl ID="SPSecurityTrimmedControl2" runat="server" PermissionsString="EditListItems">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("s4-ribbonrow").style.display = "block";
    </script>
</Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>
<!-- Page Start -->
    </div>
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td align="center">
<table  width="100%"cellspacing="0" border="0" bgcolor="#727272">
<tr class="ribbonUserInfo"><td align="center">
      <tr class="customBanner">
         <img src="imageurl.png" alt /> <!--  Put the banner here! -->
      </tr>
```

Comment: We want the banner to display for everyone even users with read only access.

Comment: This should be completed if the image is correctly displayed on the master page unless the image is in a library that is not permissioned for universal access. If anything sounds like the document lives in a location that not everyone has at least read permissions to.

Comment: Also if he is putting the content in the area of the code he specified only folks with contribute access and higher will be able to see it because they will be able to see the ribbon. If they have read only they will not see the ribbon and not see the image. I think the placement of the code is the issue.

Comment: It is in the Site Assets folder, everyone that can visit the site has the same permissions in that document library. So everyone in the company has read access at least.

Comment: I'm telling you my friend it's an issue with the placement of the code. Please see my example...I have a tr with the class customBanner that's where your snipit should start.[code]<tr class="customBanner">
         <img src="imageurl.png" alt /> <!--  Put the banner here! -->
      </tr>[/code]

Comment: @swimmerbhs in your OP your code does not include the end permission tag - Just move the following line: `</Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>` up to just under the `</script>` - but make sure you are not exposing anything BUT the banner.